# HTTP Request JSON: Unexpected .parse error - How do I exterminate it?

Tags: javascript, json, api, http, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Bluemix to make a web service for a school project.

My project needs to request a JSON from an API, so I can use the data it provides.

I am having trouble with the http request to the API service. I get the following alert in the Windows 10 Command Prompt.

> "Syntaxerror: Unexpected Token"

I know there is something wrong with my JSON request, but is it exactly?

Here is my `.js` file and a print of the error screen I get when running it.

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// HTTP request - duas alternativas
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

//chama o express, que abre o servidor
var express = require('express');

// create a new express server 
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    // print a message when the server starts listening
    console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});


app.get('/home1', function(res){
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function(res){
  var body = '';
  res.on('data', function(chunk){
   body += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function(){
   var json = JSON.parse(body);
  });
  var json = JSON.parse(res);
  var cotacao = json["bovespa"]["cotacao"];
 
  console.log("A sua cotação é "+cotacao);
 
 });
});
```

[Print of the Error Screen in the Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMflr.png)

Comment: you're trying to JSON.parse teh res object - `var json = JSON.parse(res);` - res in **not** a JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the json object you created in `.on('end'`

trying to JSON.parse `res` when `res` is clearly not a string is causing your error (res.toString() results in [Object object] ... hence the error as that is not valid JSON

```
app.get('/home1', function(res){
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function(res){
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var cotacao = json["bovespa"]["cotacao"];

            console.log("A sua cotação é "+cotacao);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring app for parsing json body:

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.json())
})
```

You will recieve a parsed json object